# Possible starting letters of uuid4() in Python

Tags: python

I'm using uuid4() to generate random names for my files. However, I need to know the possible starting letters for these files. Can the uuid4()'s only start with [a-z,A-Z,0-9] or can they also include punctuation characters like [_-,]? I cannot find a reference for this.

Comment: Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my question isn't that well-received. I'll delete it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using hex and so it would be 0-f.

Otherwise from the spec it is:
UUID.hex
The UUID as a 32-character hexadecimal string.

UUID.int
The UUID as a 128-bit integer.

UUID.urn
The UUID as a URN as specified in RFC 4122.

Ref -> https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt